# Sitecore: ResolveFieldBoostArgs does not contain a definition for 'FieldDefinitionItem'

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I'm trying to implement rule-based boosting for fields as described in section 5.7.2 of the [Developer's Guide to Item Buckets and Search](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/72/developer's_guide_to_item_buckets_and%20search_sc72_usletter.pdf). I've copied the code line for line with these includes, so the whole class file looks like:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.ResolveBoost.ResolveFieldBoost;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Boosting;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Diagnostics;

namespace MyNamespace.Pipeline
{
    public class RuleBasedFieldBoostResolver : BaseResolveFieldBoostPipelineProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(ResolveFieldBoostArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args.FieldDefinitionItem, "field definition item");

            var fieldItem = args.FieldDefinitionItem;

            var ruleContext = new RuleBoostingContext(fieldItem);
            var ruleItems = this.GetLocalBoostingRules(fieldItem);
            if (ruleItems == null || !ruleItems.Any())
            {
                CrawlingLog.Log.Debug(string.Format("No local rules were resolved for field {0}", fieldItem.Uri));
                return;
            }
            var rules = this.ConvertToBoostingRules<RuleBoostingContext>(ruleItems);
            try
            {
                if (rules != null)
                {
                    rules.Run(ruleContext);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                CrawlingLog.Log.Error(string.Format("Cannot resolve boost for item {0}.", fieldItem.Uri), exception);
            }
            args.ResolvedBoost += ruleContext.Boost;
        }

    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error: `ResolveFieldBoostArgs does not contain a definition for 'FieldDefinitionItem'`.

Any ideas what am I missing?

Thanks
Thad

Answer (score 0):

**Swap this line:**

```
var fieldItem = args.FieldDefinitionItem;
```

**for**

```
var fieldItem = (Item)args.FieldDefinition;
```